# Looping through subdirectories

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

I need to go through subdirectories of a directory /home/userName/ and find the files whose names begin with SY101 and their extension is .csv and transfer those files to another server. My question is how do I loop through subdirectories and keep looking for the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do several things, this is probably the most efficient, but I dont know anything about the size of your files and your link between servers, but let me try:

```
find /home/userName/ -name 'SY101*.csv' | \
xargs tar cvfz - | ssh hostname 'tar xzf -'
```

This is going to copy the files to your home on the other server.

Please note the full path will be transfered.

Comment: What do you mean by full path will be transferred?

Comment: I would recommend the `-print0` option for `find` and the `-0` option for `xargs` just in case any filenames have spaces in them.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you:

```
rsync --recursive --include='SY101*.csv' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /home/userName/ username@hostname:destdir
```

This will reproduce the directory hierarchy of the source on the destination.